# definitive guide to installing nvida drivers, cuda, and cuDDN wanted

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 18.10, cuda

Getting NVIDIA Drivers, and CUDA to install on my 18.10 laptop has been nothing short of a nightmare. From periodically breaking my graphics, to programs that straight up core dump, to inappropriate memory, VRAM usage, nothing I have done thus far has worked properly. I would like to get these things installed properly so I can move on with my life, and start programing the things I care about, but I am still uncertain how to do a proper installation. Proprietary drivers, are fine, if they will allow me to utilize my cuda cores properly.

My machine is a Lenovo legion Y530, with an NVIDIA GTX 1060 mobile, running Ubuntu Mate 18.10.

I have tried installing the Nvidia OEM, GTX 1060 mobile driver. It fails to install, and then breaks my graphics where by I left with loging in via a shell.
I have tried the repository version of cuda, (version 9.1) but it seems to be incompatible with the version of my current NVIDIA graphics, nvidia-driver-390. I havent even gotten to installing cuDNN, as problems with the first two, have prevented this.

Comment: Have you tried the 418.56 Nvidia driver from the graphics-drivers ppa?  That seems to be the highest number available there.

Comment: I have, itt is what Im running right now, but cuda 10.1 wont install yet.

Comment: I'm maxed out at CUDA8, but all that was necessary for that was (with a running Nvndia driver) was to download the Intel CUDA deb package, dpkg -i the deb into a local dir, and put in the CUDA bin and lib into PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH. No other CUDA packages needed. Copy samples to a writeable dir and make should work (for most). The samples run even on a dual boot OS sharing the dir with the CUDA install. I avoid prime and Bumblebee and Wayland (which may require additional tweaking to make things work).

Comment: At present time I have given up on getting cuda10.1 to work, with the OEM drivers. 
re-installed ubuntu but went back to 18.04. nvidia drivers, and cuda 9.0 are installed and my system isnt hopelessly broken. No idea if cuDNN works, or if the openCV libraries, and other software are going to give me compatibility problems, but Im working on it.